# Explicit class vs generics on an interface

Tags: java, generics

Let's imagine the following case:

We define a couple of VO classes:

```
abstract class A { // some class variables }

class B extends A { // more specific class variables }
```

Now, what would be the best practice when creating an interface and its implementations?

Suggestion 1:

```
interface X {
    A method1();
}

class ImplX implements X {
    public A method1() {
        return new B();
    }
}

// more class implementations of the interface
```

Suggestion 2:

```
interface X <T extends A> {
    T method1();
}

class ImplX implements X<B> {
    public B method1() {
        return new B();
    }
}

// more class implementations of the interface
```

What are the benefits and drawbacks of both implementations? What's the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier way to return a `B`, which doesn't require using generics:

```
class ImplX implements X {
    public B method1() {
        return new B();
    }
}
```

You can use covariant return types.

The thing about making `X` generic is that you then have to use the generics *everywhere*. `X<Foo>`, `X<Bar>`, `X<List<Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>>>`.... even if you don't want to care what it is, you still have to use `X<?>`.

Unless you *really* need to know that a `B` specifically will be returned by this method, keep it non-generic.